# How to prevent target="_blank" links from opening by PWA app while you visit from chrome?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, mobile-chrome

Some links on my website project have target="_blank" when I try to open it from Chrome 76/77 on Android mobile device all external links opens by PWA app which was installed (added to home screen).
I need to open my links in a new tab instead of open it in PWA app.

I also have tried to set 'scope': in my manifest file but it didn't solve my problem. Perhaps there is another property I can change to prevent such behavior.

```
{
  "name": "PWA reproducer",
  "short_name": "PWA reproducer",
  "description": "PWA reproducer",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#d0112b",
  "theme_color": "#d0112b",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen168.png",
      "sizes": "168x168",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://reproducer-domain.com/images/logos/homescreen512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "display": "standalone",
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "start_url": "https://reproducer-domain.com/?utm_source=homescreenPWA",
}
```

Expect to open target="_blank" in a new tab instead of open by PWA app in Chrome on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this will be covered by the proposal outlined at https://github.com/WICG/sw-launch/blob/master/explainer.md

I'd recommend subscribing to updates to that repo for more details.

Chrome's eventual implementation is tracked in by this [Chrome Status entry](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5734953453092864).

At the time of this writing, though, it's not something you have much control over.